# How do I set a number for each row according to two other columns in one MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a table named *members* with this structure:

```
member_id, col1, col2, number
```

Now, if I run this query:

```
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 number, member_id 
FROM members, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r ORDER BY col1 DESC, col2 DESC
```

I get a number for each row. Is it possible to assign this number to column *number* for each row?

For example, if the table contained this data:

```
1 1000 1.2 0
2 8700 1.1 0
3 1000 1.1 0
```

First row *number* column should be set to 2, second row to 1 and third row to 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a temporary table to store the values and `UPDATE` from it with a join.

```
/* Store query result in a temporary table */
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ranks AS
  SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 number, member_id FROM members, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r ORDER BY col1 DESC, col2 DESC;

/* And join against it to update your members.number column */
UPDATE 
  members
  JOIN ranks ON members.member_id = ranks.member_id
SET members.number = ranks.number;

DROP TABLE ranks;
```

Actually by my test just now I was able to do this without the temporary table. I didn't think MySQL would permit updating the same table from a subquery but apparently it is permitted with the correlated subquery.

```
UPDATE 
  members 
  /* JOIN against a subquery which returns the rank values */
  JOIN ( 
   SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 number, member_id 
   FROM members, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
   ORDER BY col1 DESC, col2 DESC
  ) ranks ON members.member_id = ranks.member_id 
/* And set the number column to the rank */
SET members.number = ranks.number;
```

[SQLfiddle.com demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9dbce/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
update members A
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 number, member_id 
    FROM members, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r 
    ORDER BY col1 DESC, col2 DESC
) B ON A.member_id = B.member_id
SET A.number = B.number;
```